# How to get records between a timeframe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, where-clause

I have a simple model called Event.

I'm trying to grab the Events that have a `scheduled_at:datetime` within the next 30 minutes.

I've tried this but it's not working like I need it do - I must be doing something wrong.

```
Event.where('scheduled_at > ?', Chronic.parse('now'))
     .where('scheduled_at < ?', Chronic.parse('30 minutes from now'))
     .find_each do |event|
  puts event.id
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
 Event.where(scheduled_at: DateTime.now..(DateTime.now + 30.mins))
```

Answer (score 0):

The below query will give you the data between the given dates and time. Better you just check the records inside the console.

```
Event.where('date(scheduled_at) > ?', Chronic.parse('now'))
     .where('date(scheduled_at) < ?', Chronic.parse('30 minutes from now'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Event.where(scheduled_at: DateTime.now..(DateTime.now + 30.minutes))

Event.where(:scheduled_at => DateTime.now..(Time.zone.now + 30.minutes))

Event.where{'scheduled_at ? '> DateTime.now & 'scheduled_at ?' < DateTime.now + 30.mins}